# Importing images with MAGMI, exclude flag is ignored after the 1st import

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

I am trying to update the images of my catalog with the following CSV:

```
store,sku,image,small_image,thumbnail,padrao,media_gallery,media_gallery_reset
admin,TP1501054-15-XS,+/TP1501054_15_1.jpg,/TP1501054_15_1.jpg,/TP1501054_15_1.jpg,/TP1501054_15_0.jpg,/TP1501054_15_2.jpg;,1
```

It works the first time I use it.
From that time forward, everything works ok except the "exclude" flag. It simply ignores it, in this case, the main image is excluded from the gallery.

If I edit the product manually and remove the gallery and re-import this CSV, the main image stays without the exclude flag.
If I re-import the same CSV again, it enables the exclude flag.

When I import the CSV it should respect the instructions in the file.

Anyone can reproduce this ?
Anyone has the solution ?

Thanks.

magmi v0.7.21

Comment: Are you sure your file is UTF-8 and valid csv? Although I create my csv files in excel, I run them through Openoffice calc to convert them to UTF-8  and get definitively valid csv files.

Comment: I use ONLY OpenOffice to work with this type of files. UTF-8.
Have you tried ? Can you replicate the behaviour ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the exclude flag. My suggestions were more general, based on issues I've had but I use excel.

Comment: Where is your exclude flag?  Exclude flags are denoted by a minus sign `-` before the image name.  You only have a `+` flag which is an **include** flag.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, @Axel, he is using the flag. It's about naming things, the Magmi uses "exclude flag" to name both the + and -.

Comment: `-` is EXCLUDE and `+` is INCLUDE. The [Magmi documentation](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Image_attributes_processor#Explicit_.E2.80.9Cexclude.E2.80.9D_flag_management.) states this `with a + , the image will be included in gallery (ie not excluded) with a - the image will be excluded from gallery `